# CSS? I'm trying to keep my video files from covering my banner

Tags: css, video

I'm coding a page where the video files will scroll, but the banner/logo is static, at the top.

Since I've added css code for the video files to dynamically scale with the page width, the video files now scroll on top of the banner/logo.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a z-index to your div that is the static header/banner  (this div does not have an id..I suggest you assign an id and add

```
z-index:1
```

example

```
#banner{
    z-index:1
}
```

Comment: I cannot say if there are other elements that have a greater z-index than 1 but and alternative is to try a higher z-index

Comment: Welcome...feel free to accept answer if it is worth it